# appendTo add dom as last element in target but how to add it as first?

Tags: jquery

I want to add element to as first as below. How can i do this ?

```
$('<li>').appendTo($('ul')); // add it as last element

<ul>
    <!-- i want to add element here -->
    <li></li>
    <li></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use jQuery's .prepend() http://api.jquery.com/prepend/

```
$('ul').prepend('<li>new</li>')
```

Comment: prepend works if source element is not inserted into document ? Because prepend didn't worked while appendTo working.

Comment: Look at the documentation for `prepend` vs. `prependTo`.

Answer (score 4):

Your looking for the `prependTo` method.